# Where is the mistake in my attempts : $\cos(\arctan(-2)) ?$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to calculate this simple problem

> $$\cos(\arctan(-2))$$

My attempts,

$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$
$$\tan^2x+1=\frac1{\cos^2x}$$
$$\cos x= ±\sqrt{\frac1{\tan^2x+1}}$$

Then, I wrote $\tan x=-2$ where $x=\arctan(-2)$ then, I must find $\cos x=?$

I find $$\cos x=±\frac1{\sqrt5}$$ or $$\cos(\arctan(-2))=±\frac1{\sqrt5}$$

Where is the mistake in my attempts? Because the answer is $$\cos(\arctan(-2))=\frac1{\sqrt5}$$

Comment: You found the answer to the related question: if $\tan x = -2$, then what is $\cos x$?  If the tangent function were injective, this would be the same question; but tangent is not injective, so $\arctan z$ is selected in a specific way from among all solutions to $\tan x = z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take only the positive square root, because $\arctan(-2)\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ and therefore $\cos\bigl(\arctan(-2)\bigr)>0$.

Comment: How can I prove  $\arctan(-2)\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ ?

Comment: By definition, $\arctan$ is the inverse of the restriction of the tangent function to $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$. Therefore,$$(\forall x\in\mathbb R):\arctan(x)\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for explaining.

Comment: And is the method I am using correct?

Comment: Yes. Besides what I wrote, what you did is just fine.